# Use Javascript to change Title Column Color based on Drop-Down Selection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, formatting

I have an announcement list slider (using the Hillbilly slider set up.)  I've added a heading section that pulls the Title field of the announcement list.  I would like to add some Javascript that will change the `<h2>` tag to a color chosen from a drop down column in the announcement list.

I've tried to using the formatting in SharePoint Designer to change the list itself but it seems like the title field can be formatted.  Would anyone be able to help.

Basically the formula would be "if Text Color" equal 'green' set `<h2>` to `color: green;`.  I just don't know how to write the formula.

Comment: post your code if you could by editing the post, it's surely just a minor tweak to your script

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SharePoint 2013, 2016 or SharePoint Online? If yes, may be Client Side Rendering (JS Link) could be an approach.

I love client side rendering its a very nice feature. Here are some examples:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

But it's not available in SharePoint 2010

Comment: If you go CSR/JSLink find anything you can by Andrei Markeev and his Cisar Chrome Extension